# Why is the titlebar overlapping view controller content?

Tags: xcode, macos, interface-builder

Can anyone tell me why this is happening and how can I fix this? I thought the content is suppose to display after the titlebar, not under it. The only way for me to fix this is to create a new project.

[image: Window doesn't load up view controller correctly]

The Button on top is being overlapped by the titlebar. Not sure how that became possible. There's a lot of room for the window to adjust the view controller but not sure why it's not doing that.

Comment: Why haven't you positioned the button within the "safe" area. You really should be using auto layout constraints and the safe area (or what ever they are called on Mac) guidelines to layout you controls

Comment: @MadProgrammer Safe area doesn't work. It continues to overlap. I'm not sure if this is actually a bug in Xcode. From what I see, its as if the view controller is locked from top, ignoring anything that uses that top section. This does not happen if I start a fresh new project which is why I'm baffled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check window properties. You might have enabled “Full Size Content View” property.

Comment: You're right, I unchecked that property and now the window resizes properly. Not sure how that property got enabled by itself but thanks for the help!